# Javascript get image src from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, nested-loops

I have a table with images inside every cell. I need to get the image src from the individual cell. Table creation is dynamic so the cell's id is incremented from 1 upwards. Here is a sample of my code:

```
var i = 0;
for (h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        var src = null;
        if (document.querySelector("#gridcells grid1 img").src === null) {
            src = "random";
        } else {
            src = document.querySelector("#gridcells grid{i} img").src;
        }
        alert(src);
        i++;
    }
}
```

When doing this however, it produces an error - "cannot read property of src null". I have uploaded more of the source code so you can see it running here:

https://jsfiddle.net/oecc4gpj/4/

Thanks

Comment: In your fiddle the `height` and `width` vars are not in scope of the `get()` function.

Comment: This is only a small snippet from my code, the height and width are included in the scope, see the jsfiddle for the full function.

Comment: I am referring to the fiddle ...?

Comment: You have tagged this with jquery but it contains no jquery code?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, I have updated this now. Tushar submitted a working answer.

Comment: @Liam, I am using jquery in the project source, again.. see the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each` to loop over all the images:

```
$('#gridcells img').each(function() {
    if ( !$(this).attr('src')) ) {
        $(this).attr('src', 'random');
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/oecc4gpj/2/

Comment: that's amazing! Did not know I could do this. Thank you!

Comment: They need to be added to a nested object, is this possible inside a nested foreach loop?

Comment: @NicholasMordecai No need of nesting, this will get `src` for all the images inside `gridcell`

Comment: however, how do I push them to the right object? The object for a 4x4 grid should loop like this.. var Map = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[4,2,1,4],[3,2,1,4]]
This is where the image source should replace the numbers.